# Server Migration 03 -> 12

Tags: active-directory, migration, ntp

I have run into a wall and out of ideas. Here's the situation. I have a client that has a old '03 DC with a 12 replicating the '03 server. It is out dated and has to many group policies and stuff it doesnt need. Plus it was name as their domain (web domain - xyz.com and guy before me named it xyz.com instead of a subdomain eww).

So i have decided to set them up with a whole new domain properly named and everything.

What i have done so far. Set up NEW DC as ab.xyz.com, DNS is set up properly. I can ping the old DC from the new DC via name and vice-versa. The old DC and new DC have a functioning 2 way trust (verified and working). I have changed the FSMO's over to the old DC's 12 server as well. Every thing seems to be working just fine.

I cannot get my account from the new DC added to the old domain for ADMT. I have an account set up on the target and source domain called ad_migrate, each are part of a local group, called admt, that have local admin and domain properties for their respected DC's. I cannot get ad_migrate on source to inherent the admt user memberships from the target domain. I cannot add any users or groups from source to target or target to source.

I get the error "the clocks on the client and server machines are skewed." when trying to add them from the '03 server and "the server is not operational" from the replicating 12 server. Seeing the time error i said ok ill just just change the NTP to a public time clock. Still no luck. I then change the NTP on the old DC to look to the new DC for time. The clocks are in sync to the second and are in the same time zone.

The weird part is i can create a share folder on old DC and giver permission JUST to a user on the new DC and he can access it just fine.

Going on about 12 hours of trouble shooting and can't get this to resolve. Any help would be greatly appreciated before i go crazy =p.

I guess my question would be if any one has any ideas? My googlefu is letting me down.

I have installed ADMT 3.2 and cannot get accounts to migrate over because of the above.

Comment: I can feel your frustration, but step back and try to think what the actual problem is, because there is not yet a single question mark in your story... Which is kind of difficult in a Q&A site.

Comment: yeah i wrote this before lunch so my hunger took over haha. I don't really have a yes no question, im just seeking advice and see if anyone else has had this issue or any ideas. My tank is running on empty. I know thats broad and vague but if i knew the exact issue id probably be able to fix it.